# why does it matter if the #include are in the .h file or in .cpp file?

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a cpp file contains this include:

```
#include "twitServer.h"
```

and in twitServer.h I have:

```
#ifndef twitServer_twitServer_h
#define twitServer_twitServer_h
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "twitUser.h"

using namespace std;

void startServer(string port);

#endif
```

But the Xcode says for this line:

```
if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, port, &hints, &ai)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "selectserver: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    exit(1);
}
```

that the `getaddrinfo` is not defined... why that?

if the includes are in the cpp file it works fine how comes

Comment: Putting using namespace std; in the header file should not be done. It defeats using a namespace.

Comment: If you put the `#include`s in the cpp file, the `using namespace std;` thing comes before the `#include`s. I don't know if that's causing this, but it may make a difference.

Comment: Any cpp including that header is going to have a lot of work to do when compiling after a change. It's better to put what you need in each individual file.

Comment: At the very least, you should try to get rid of the duplicated `#include`s there -- just for a couple of examples, you're including `<netinet/in.h>` and `<netdb.h>` twice each, as well as `<cstring>` along with `<string.h>` and `<cstdlib>` along with `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to fix your problem, but by convention, you should never include in the header file, because you might write code some day, needing your header file, but not all the includes.

Answer (score 0):

Try including Ws2tcpip.h and see if that solves the problem. This is what MSDN has to say about it (see the requirements section)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Also, let me say that this seems like an awful lot of header files included and some should not be matched unless you really know what you are doing. There are quite a bit of C++ headers (iostream (which is included twice by the way), cstdio, cstdlib, algorithm, list, string, ctime...) mixed with C headers (stdio.h, stdlib.h string.h). Maybe it's time for some late spring cleaning in there :)