# why does xcode 4.4.1 give error while trying to use getaddrinfo ?

Tags: c++, xcode, sockets, xcode4.4, getaddrinfo

I am using xcode 4.4.1 to do socket programming in c++. I think i have included required header file. But i still get error saying:

" No matching function for call to 'getaddrinfo' ".

There was duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071678/why-does-it-matter-if-the-include-are-in-the-h-file-or-in-cpp-file)
The header files that i have included are

```
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
```

Comment: What SDK are you using?  For example, OS X 10.7, OS X 10.8, iOS 5.1?

Comment: Show how you call the function. C++ does that overloading thing ...

Comment: the problem was with parameters of getaddrinfo .. i used int insted of char* for the port number. Thank you all for the comment.

Comment: Show the code that calls `getaddrinfo()`.

Comment: my address is string ; my PORT was #define PORT 80 : getaddrinfo((char*)address,(char*)PORT,&hints,&servinfo) ... typecasting with (char*) did it ..

Comment: you can also do getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1","80",&hints,&servinfo) too